# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. in kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI grid on one of my page.

I want to show all users in grid using membership object.

```
@model IEnumerable<MembershipUser>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Gridusers")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.UserName).Width(100);

})
.Sortable()
.Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true)))
```

When I come to this page after getting list of users from controller it is giving error

> "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

It is working fine when I'm using the old Telerik MVC grid but not with Kendo UI grid.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 10):

The Kendo UI grid needs the bound model to have a parameterless constructor because it instantiates an instance of it. In your case you could add an empty constructor to the `MembershipUser` class:

```
public class MembershipUser
{
     public MembershipUser()
     {
     }

     /* other methods */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Atanas Korchev,

But I am using System.Web.Security and don't want to create sub class for this.

Comment: See my reply. Your model needs to have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I cannot create  constructor in MembershipUser class because by default it is locked due to System.Web.Security.

I am using MVC4 asp.net.

Comment: I will repeat. The Kendo UI grid needs a parameterless constructor. If your class doesn't have one you can't use it. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be clear that Telerik is going to construct an instance of the bound classes as well as that classes members.  For example if your grid is bound to Dogs ...

```
public class Dog {
   public DogKind Kind { get; set; }
   public Dog() {
   }
}
```

then your "DogKind" class also has to have a default constructor.